# Is this the correct way to handle two similar objects in realm?

Tags: ios, swift, core-data, swift3, realm

I am working on a money tracker app where I have two different objects. One is 'Transaction' which contains all the transactions that happened and the second one is 'RecurringTransaction' which contains all the recurring transactions.

I use Recurring transaction like a template which contains all the information required to create a transaction. I am giving an option to clear the transaction, so once user clears the recurring transaction then only I create a transaction. I am using Realm in my app.

These are that objects:

```
class Transaction: Object {

  dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  dynamic var title: String = ""
  dynamic var amount: Double = 0
  dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
  dynamic var category: Category?
  dynamic var recurringTransaction: RecurringTransaction?
  dynamic var type: TransactionType = .Income
}

class RecurringTransaction: Object {

  dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
  dynamic var title: String = ""
  dynamic var amount: Double = 0
  dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
  dynamic var category: Category?
  dynamic var type: TransactionType = .Income
  dynamic var frequency: TransactionFrequency = .Monthly
}
```

Is this the correct way to do it? As you can see both contains similar properties but at the same time both are different: one is actual transaction and another one is kind of a template.

And one more question what would be different if I use coredata? as I don't have much experience with the coredata

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Realm supports subclassing of objects to a limited degree. If you subclass an `Object` off another `Object` subclass, the subclass will include all of the properties of the superclass, as well as its own ones. This will create two separate tables in the database, tracking each type.

As a result, you shouldn't need to have redundant property names. Something like this should work:

```
class Transaction: Object {
    dynamic var id: String = UUID().uuidString
    dynamic var title: String = ""
    dynamic var amount: Double = 0
    dynamic var createdAt: Date = Date()
    dynamic var category: Category?
    dynamic var recurringTransaction: RecurringTransaction?
    dynamic var type: TransactionType = .Income
}

class RecurringTransaction: Transaction {
    dynamic var frequency: TransactionFrequency = .Monthly
}
```

(Full disclosure: I work for Realm) I wouldn't recommend trying Core Data if Realm is an option and you're not experienced at Core Data. The learning curve and the amount of boilerplate code required doesn't make it a very easy thing to implement.

Comment: Thanks. I was little confused. One more question what if I want to have a different primary key? Right now I have the same primary key for both the models but if in case I want to change. And What limitations I will have by subclassing?

Comment: No problems! Feel free to mark the answer correct if this answered your question. :D Yeah, so `Transaction` and `RecurringTransaction` would still be wholly separate entities. Their primary keys wouldn't overlap at all. No other limitations other than what I said: they're treated as two discrete entities.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. :)

Comment: I am getting an error 'cannot override static method' if I try to change the primary key in `RecurringTransaction`.

Answer (score 0):

What about a single `Transaction` class with `frequency` being optional?
If it is set to `nil`, it's a normal transaction, and if it has a value it's a recurring transaction. If you want to split classes, `RecurringTransaction`could be a subclass of `Transaction` which just adds the `frequency` field.

Comment: I want to keep them separate as I don't create transaction till it is paid and if I want to add a new property it will be empty most of the time.